# formatting json in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

I am at a loss on the `SerializeJSON` output of a CFQUERY.  The below code:

```
<cfsetting showdebugoutput="yes">
<cfheader name="Content-Type" value="application/json">

<cftry>
<cfquery name="GetData" datasource="dsn">
  with cte as (
      select distinct ZipCode from db.dbo.table1 where ZipCode in (#URL.Zip#)
  )
  SELECT
      cte.ZipCode
      , '##' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(3), 2) as Color
  from cte
</cfquery>

<cfoutput>
#SerializeJSON(GetData)#
</cfoutput>

  <cfcatch type="any">
    Error: <cfoutput>#cfcatch.message#</cfoutput>
  </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

creates this output:

```
{"COLUMNS":["ZIPCODE","COLOR"],"DATA":[["54814","#3269B7"],["60050","#DC3E08"]]}
```

when the `#URL.ZIP#` variable = `60050,54814`

I need the `DATA` component to have the JSON formatted with the zip code as a key and the color code as a data value.

How do I tell `SerializeJSON` I need it that way?

Thanks

Comment: You really don't.  You create a new structure {}, loop over the query, and set myStruct[myQuery.zipCode] = myQuery.color.   Then you serializeJSON(myStruct)

Comment: Consider adding returntype=“array” to cfquery.

Comment: You should use cfqueryparam when using url parameters (#URL.Zip#) in query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can you the 2nd argument(`queryFormat`) in [`SerializeJSON(data[, queryFormat[, useSecureJSONPrefix[, useCustomSerializer]]])`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/serializejson.html)

```
serializeJSON(GetData, 'STRUCT')
```

The result will look something like this.

> [{"ZIPCODE": "54814","COLOR": "#3269B7"}, {"ZIPCODE": "60050","COLOR": "#DC3E08"}]